# Show a List when a RadioButton is clicked in JavaFX

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, tableview

I'm looking for a way to show a List of "Companies", only when is clicked one of the two RadioButtons, in my GUI.

Here's the code:

```
public class CompaniesChoice {
    private BorderPane borderOnce;
    private HBox hb;
    private final ToggleGroup group;
    private Text companies;
    private Button goOn;
    private RadioButton btnDefault;
    private RadioButton btnPersonalized;
    private GridPane secondaryPane;
    /*TODO: add List of Companies*/

public CompaniesChoice(){
    borderOnce = new BorderPane();
    secondaryPane = new GridPane();
    goOn = new Button("Continue");

    companies = new Text("Companies");
    btnDefault = new RadioButton("Default");
    btnPersonalized = new RadioButton("Personalized");
    secondaryPane.add(companies, 0, 0);
    secondaryPane.add(btnDefault, 1, 0);
    secondaryPane.add(btnPersonalized, 2, 0);
    secondaryPane.setVgap(25.0);
    secondaryPane.setHgap(25.0);

    group = new ToggleGroup();

    btnDefault.setToggleGroup(group);
    btnDefault.setSelected(true);

    btnPersonalized.setToggleGroup(group);

    borderOnce.setTop(secondaryPane);
    //borderOnce.setCenter(List of companies);
    borderOnce.setBottom(goOn);

    hb = new HBox();
    hb.getChildren().add(borderOnce);
    hb.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
}

public HBox getPane() {
    return this.hb;
}
}
```

Well, my idea is to create something like this:
[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Hk7O.png)

By now, forget the "Name" and "Value" Objects.
I need to know instead who to show the TableView only when i click on "Personalized" RadioButton.

Thank you

Comment: Use a listener to do set/unset the `center` property when the selected toggle changes...

Comment: Thank you @fabian
I had the same idea, but I really don't know how to do it, can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a listener to the `ToggleGroup.selected` or the `Toggle.selected` property that adds or removes the list from the parent. In this case since you're using `BorderPane`, you can also bind the center property depending on the selected toggle:

```
Node nodeToDisplay = ...; // in this case use the ListView/TableView
borderOnce.centerProperty().bind(Bindings.when(btnPersonalized.selectedProperty())
                                         .<Node>then(nodeToDisplay)
                                         .otherwise((Node) null));
```

#### Alternative with a listener

```
btnPersonalized.selectedProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (newValue) {
        borderOnce.setCenter(nodeToDisplay);
    } else {
        borderOnce.setCenter(null);
    }
});
```

In this case you need to make sure the initial state of the GUI is "valid".